# Relation between the energy of a capacitor and the force it applies

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential-energy, capacitance

I have a capacitor with stored energy $U$. I do not understand the relation $\vec{F}=-\vec\nabla U$, where $\vec{F}$ is the force that the capacitor applies on the charge inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you confused the concepts of potential energy of the particle inside the capacitor and the electrostatic energy stored by the capacitor itself. They are different things, though they have in common the dependence on the electric field.
Without loss of generality in the following I'll assume no dielectric medium is present.

Inside the capacitor you have an electric field $\vec{E}(\vec{x}) = -\nabla V (\vec{x})$ (because $\vec{E}$ it's conservative). The force on a charge $q$ (a test charge, i.e. not altering the distribution of charges around it) is simply given by the formula you wrote:
$$
\vec{F}(\vec{x}) = q\vec{E}(\vec{x}) = - q \nabla V (\vec{x}) = - \nabla U_{particle} (\vec{x})
$$

Note that the above force is defined point-wise, and in general depends on the geometric shape of the capacitor. The infinite parallel-plates capacitor is a particular case in which the above force is independent of the position and equal to:
$$\vec{F} = q \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0} \hat{n} $$

Now let's come to the energy stored in the capacitor.
The electrostatic energy density is given by:
$$u(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 E^2(\vec{x})$$

The total energy stored in the capacitor is then given by:

$$
U_{stored} = \int d \vec{x} \, u(\vec{x}) = 
\frac{1}{2} \epsilon_0 \int d \vec{x} \, E^2(\vec{x}) 
$$

Again, a particular case is the parallel-plates capacitor, for which:

$$U_{stored} = \frac{S d}{2 \epsilon_0} \sigma^2 = \frac{Q^2}{2C}  $$

As you see, $U_{particle}$ and $U_{stored}$ are different.
In the case of the parallel-plates capacitor, if you differentiate the latter with respect to $d$ you get the force needed to keep the armatures separated.

Comment: I agree that  $U_{stored}$ and $U_{particle}$ are different things, but if I want calculate the force on a dielectric matter inside the capacitor than I should use the formula $\vec{F}=-\vec\nabla U_{stored}$ ? I am not sure in what condition this formula is valid.

Comment: No, you cannot use it. A dielectric is a generic piece of matter, so the net force on it is found as:
$$\vec{F}_{net}=\int d \vec{x} \rho(\vec{x}) \vec{E} (\vec{x})$$

When you write $\vec{F} (\vec{x}) = - \nabla U_{stored} (\vec{x})$ you find the force the first armature exerts on the infinitesimal piece of the second armature located at $\vec{x}$. For a parallel-plates capacitor this force is the same over the hole armature and equal to:
$$ F = - \nabla U_{stored} = -\partial_d U_{stored}(d) = -\frac{S \sigma^2}{2 \epsilon_0} = -\frac{Q \sigma }{2 \epsilon_0} $$